# invalid URL escape "%" when docker push

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I set up a registry at docker-registry.elektron.space and when I want to push an image with `$ docker push docker-registry.elektron.space/boxbeat-media-server`, the upload animation is running in loop for each entity passing from "Pushing" state to "Retrying in X seconds".

After a while I get this error:

```
failed to parse Location header "https://docker-registry.elektron.space/v2/boxbeat-media-server/blobs/uploads/56244149-c196-439a-85bf-af1121e0b84b%?_state=h1lqY-NljkLbgzTCjd8jxcfdscojPHApblWu-45ISK57Ik5hbWUiOiJib3hiZWF0LW1lZGlhLXNlcnZlciIsIlVVSUQiOiI1NjI0NDE0OS1jMTk2LTQzOWEtODViZi1hZjExMjFlMGI4NGIiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMDFUMTU6MzI6NTAuMzcxNjc5NTc5WiJ9": parse https://docker-registry.elektron.space/v2/boxbeat-media-server/blobs/uploads/56244149-c196-439a-85bf-af1121e0b84b%?_state=h1lqY-NljkLbgzTCjd8jxcfdscojPHApblWu-45ISK57Ik5hbWUiOiJib3hiZWF0LW1lZGlhLXNlcnZlciIsIlVVSUQiOiI1NjI0NDE0OS1jMTk2LTQzOWEtODViZi1hZjExMjFlMGI4NGIiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMDFUMTU6MzI6NTAuMzcxNjc5NTc5WiJ9: invalid URL escape "%"
```

In a readable way:

```
failed to parse Location header 

"https://docker-registry.elektron.space/v2/boxbeat-media-server/blobs/uploads/
56244149-c196-439a-85bf-af1121e0b84b%?_state=
h1lqY-NljkLbgzTCjd8jxcfdscojPHApblWu-45ISK57Ik5hbWUiOiJib3hiZWF0LW1lZGlhLXNlcnZlciIsIlVVSUQiOiI1NjI0NDE0OS1jMTk2LTQzOWEtODViZi1hZjExMjFlMGI4NGIiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMDFUMTU6MzI6NTAuMzcxNjc5NTc5WiJ9": 

parse https://docker-registry.elektron.space/v2/boxbeat-media-server/blobs/uploads/
56244149-c196-439a-85bf-af1121e0b84b%?_state=
h1lqY-NljkLbgzTCjd8jxcfdscojPHApblWu-45ISK57Ik5hbWUiOiJib3hiZWF0LW1lZGlhLXNlcnZlciIsIlVVSUQiOiI1NjI0NDE0OS1jMTk2LTQzOWEtODViZi1hZjExMjFlMGI4NGIiLCJPZmZzZXQiOjAsIlN0YXJ0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMDFUMTU6MzI6NTAuMzcxNjc5NTc5WiJ9: 

invalid URL escape "%"
```

Where does this "%" come from? I thought this could come from `zsh` then I tried to run it with `bash` but same result.

Any idea?

Comment: What did you write?

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the oversight

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a % sign is used to initiate an escape sequence in [url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP). You need to escape the % itself.

So in your case you should replace the `%` with `%25` which is the escaped form if it. That way you don't get the error because the parser doesn't think an escape sequence is about to start when it sees the `%`

```
... /uploads/56244149-c196-439a-85bf-af1121e0b84b%25 ...
```

[This article can also help to understand things better.](https://love2dev.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-encodeuri-and-encodeuricomponent) Even though its about javascript, the information is applicable much broader.

You can lookup escape sequences on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).